# How bad is this jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().children()[0]).html()
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how bad the code is.

Comment: @Malachi I would say it's definitely lacking proper context, but if it weren't *stub code* I'd vote to leave open.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about stub code. See point 3 `Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?` in our [Help Center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Also could use a bit more context.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()
```

This can be much simplified by using `parents()` which returns an array, which you can just access with an index. I.e. you can replace the above with:

```
.parents()[5]
```

The upsides of this, besides being more concise, are that it the reader of your code can see which parent you're accessing without having to count the calls to `parent` and that if you ever need to access a different parent, you can just change the number instead of having to add or remove calls to `parent`.

Comment: For the record, the slightly more ‘jQuery’ way to do this would be `.parents().get(5)`. But obviously sepp2k’s suggestion is more efficient (no overhead because of an extra function call) and shorter.

Comment: You can also do stuff like this.
`.parents('form :first');` first being immediate parent to last being outermost container.

Answer (score 14):

This...is pretty bad. But there's no real way to tell how bad it has to be given other constraints. For instance, if this is a JS file meant to affect a page whose HTML you don't have control over, then you can't do *much* better than something like

```
$(this).parents(":eq(5)").children(":eq(0)").html()
```

If this is an element you have to access a lot, consider adding an id or class to it, then selecting by that.

```
$("#fifth-parent-first-child").html() //or something descriptive
```

Again, if you don't have access to the HTML, you'll need to add it yourself at runtime

```
$(document).ready(
     function () {
         $(foo).parents(":eq(5)").children(":eq(0)").addClass("something-descriptive")
     }
);
$(".something-descriptive").html()
```

Consider pasting some surrounding code for more insight.

Comment: Applying a tag in the HTML is the best approach, and applying a tag dynamically is next. Specifying the number of parent elements as a number is fragile--your code will break if the page's structure is modified.

Comment: Using `:eq(5)` as a selector is significantly more expensive then calling `.eq(5)` if your not doing complex composition always use the cheaper methods instead.

Comment: @JoshEarl - I very much agree, I have had a lot of mysteries and headaches dealing with other's jQuery code which relies on the page structure.

Answer (score 10):

Besides what sepp2k said:

Instead of accessing the DOM object of the first child and then rewrapping it in a jQuery object, you can use the method `.eq()` to access it directly.

So instead of this:

```
$($(this)/* ... */.children()[0]).html()
```

Use this:

```
$(this)/* ... */.children().eq(0).html()
```

And there are possibly more ways to optimize it, if you show the HTML it's operating on.

Comment: Thanks, that was one of the things I was looking for, very helpful :)

Comment: Can you combine your answers into `$($(this).parents().eq(5).children().eq(0)).html()`?

Comment: Not quite. `$(this).parents().eq(5).children().eq(0).html()` See also Inaimathi's answer.

Answer (score 8):

**1.** Instead of doing so many `.parent()` calls, you can use `.parents()`:

```
$(this).parents(':eq(5)');
```

**2.** You can use `.eq()` to get the n<sup>th</sup> occurrence of an element, you don't need to do `[0]` and pass it to jQuery again.

```
$($(this).parents(':eq(5)').children()[0]).html()
```

This is better:

```
$(this).parents(':eq(5)').children().eq(0).html();
```

Though jQuery has a `:first-child` selector, which is more understandable:

```
$(this).parents(':eq(5)').find(':first-child').html();
```

**Reference**

- [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents)
- [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com)
- [`:first-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have access to the html (where you could assign an id the child), the only real option you have is:

```
$(this).parents().eq(5).children().eq(0).html();
```

if you are going to be accessing the element more than once you could assign it on load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     window.foo = $(bar).parents().eq(5).children().eq(0);
});
...
foo.html();
```

knowing more about why you need to do dom traversing, may yield further advice.